# Angular2 wait until one component subscription completes

Tags: angular, rxjs, observable

I have custom component that gets countries and a sets one from data service on its initialization. How to pass message that it has done its job to another component?

- PeopleParentComponent - holds search model and on init sends data to grid (has PeopleDataService in constructor)

  - SearchChildComponent - SearchModel

    - CountrySelectorComponent - SearchModel.Country - gets data from commonDataService on Init and sets the proper country for user
  - GridChildComponent - recives the data from parent

When PeopleParentComponent runs it builds SearchChildComponent -> CountrySelectorComponent. Also during that time on Init it gets data from peopleDataService for grid, but the search model is not complete since CountrySelectorComponent is getting its countries and a selected one. I can run it after the search components are filed and get the message manually, but how to do it after all have been set?

Something that would post message to ParentComponent -> we are done with getting the data for search, you can get data for grid.

EDIT:

CountrySelectComponent

```
 @Component({
 selector: 'country-select',
 template: ` //wrapper around custom select`,
 providers: [{ provide: NG_VALUE_ACCESSOR, useExisting: CountrySelectComponent, multi: true,}]
 })
 export class CountrySelectComponent implements ControlValueAccessor, OnInit {
     private data : CountryModel[]
     private countryModel : CountryModel;
     constructor(private commonDataService : CommonDataService){}
     ngOnInit(){
     this.commonDataService.getCountires().subscribe(
         data => {this.data = data; this.value = data[0]}) //gets data from server and sets the first value
     }
 {
 ... implemetation of ControlValueAccessor
```

SearchComponent

```
 @Component({
     selector: 'people-search',
     tempalte: `
         <country-select ngModel]="value?.country" (ngModelChange)="value?.country? value.country= $event : null"'></country-select>
         //Some other controllers like country select`
         <button (click)='performSearch()
     }),
     providers: [{ provide: NG_VALUE_ACCESSOR, useExisting: SearchComponent , multi: true,}]
 export class SearchComponent implements ControlValueAccessor {
     @Output() searchEmitter = new EventEmitter(); 
     peroformSearch(){
         this.searchEmitter.emit(true)//the data is inside Model so it passes just boolean to run a method in Parent - this could be changed?
     }
     ... implemetation of ControlValueAccessor
 }
```

ParentComponent

```
@Component({
selector: 'people',
template: `
<people-search [(ngModel)]='searchModel' (searchEmitter)='perform'></people-search>
<people-grid [gridDataStore]='gridDataStore'></people-grid>
`
})
export class PeopleComponent implements onInit{
searchModel : PeopleSearchModel = new PeopleSearchModel();
gridDataStore : CustomStore;

constructor(private peopleService : PeopleService){}
ngOnInit(){
this.gridDataStore = new CustomStore({
    load : (opts) => {
        //some paging and sorting
        return this.peopleService.getPeople(this.searchModel).toPromise().then(data =>{
            return { data : data.data, totalCount : data.totalCount} }}}) //Fetches the grid data before the search model is complete !
    }
}
```

Edit2:
I have tried to create Resolver on Routing.

```
@Injectable()
export class CommonDataCountryResolver implements Resolve<Country[]> {

constructor(private commonService: CommonDataService, private router: Router) { }
resolve(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot): CountryModel[] | Promise<CountryModel[]> | Observable<CountryModel[]> {
    return this.commonService.getCountries().toPromise().then(countries=> {
        if (countries) {
            return countries;
        } else { //not found
            this.router.navigate(['/home']);
            return false;
        }
    });
}
```

}

Routes

```
...
 children: [
 { path: 'People', component: PeopleComponent, resolve: { countries: CommonDataCountriesResolver } },
...
```

and now the CountrySelectorComponents got

```
constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute,

ngOnInit() {
    this.route.data.subscribe(
        (data: { countries: any }) => {
            this.data = data.countries;
            if (data)
                this.value = data.countries[0];
        }
    );
```

It works, but still got the problem.

1. The ngInit of resolver goes first and gives me list
2. ngInit of Parent component starts... which is bad since it tries to update grid with search model.
3. nhInit of SearchComponent and then ngInit of Child - CountrySelectorComponent.

Edit3:

Im a bit closer to the answer.
I have added emitter to search component and it emits on  ngAfterViewInit(), which is after all components are set, and added *ngIf for grid creation in parent.

But this gave me other problem: 
My country data list is working good, and sets the [0] element at the start, but after that i got ngModel from search component that overrides the country that was chosen with empty model.

Comment: Please show the code

Answer (score 0):

> Something that would post message to ParentComponent -> we are done
>   with getting the data for search, you can get data for grid.

in child component :

```
@Component({
  selector: 'child-complnent',
})
export class childComponent implements OnInit {
  @Output() notifyThatWorkIsComplete = new EventEmitter();

  ngOnInit() {
    // get data for search and when it's complete do
    this.notifyThatWorkIsComplete.emit();
  }

  constructor(){}
}
```

in parent component's template put comething like

```
<child-component (notifyThatWorkIsComplete)="getDataForGrid()"></child-component>
```

Comment: I thought about that simple answer. So my child component (countrySelect) would give an information about completion to the search component, and it would give same info to parent component, and then when parent is complete the *ngIf would generate grid component. 
But with many child components the Search would be packed with a lot of methods, its possible to pass the boolean in ngModel like : Countries[], selectedCountry, isActive ... but still it wouldn't look good.